# reference to 'rank' is ambiguous

Tags: c++11, compiler-errors

I tried so hard to figure out where my mistake is! Here my functions :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
bool lessThan(int a , int b) {   return (a<b);   }

int rank(int a[] , int n , int value , int lo , int hi) {
    if(lo > hi)  return -1;
    int mid = (lo + hi) / 2;
         if(value < a[mid]) return rank(a , n , value , lo , mid - 1); 
    else if(value > a[mid]) return rank(a , n , value , mid + 1 , hi);
    else return mid;
}

int rank(int a[] , int n , int value) {
    sort(a , a + n , lessThan);
    return rank(a , n , value , 0 , n - 1);
}
```

It is a function to check if the array contains the value . I thought i was passing the array to rank() the wrong way so i tried this :

```
void test(int a[] , int n) {
         for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i) cout << a[i];
    }
```

but it worked and made me so confused. Please tell me where my mistake is.

Comment: Please show the full unedited error message incliding the asssociated line number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compile your code with `-std=c++03` mode or change `rank` name because since c++11 there is `rank` struct in library - [rank](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/rank/). You can remove `using namespace std;` line to avoid this error, but then you need to add std:: prefix before every call of standard library function i.e. std::sort.

Comment: It works now . Thank you so much . But i have a question about your answer : you said that there is rank struct in library - rank . But i didnt #include it in my program . So why did the compiler got me error .

Comment: @VănHữu `rank` is defined in `type_traits` header, you didn't include this file explicitly, but it was included by `algorithm` header.